# Understanding the never type in TypeScript 2

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

While taking a look at what's new in TypeScript 2.0, I've found the `never` type. According to the docs, it seems like it's a clever way of setting the type of functions that never return.

Now, if I read everything correctly, then `never` can be assignable to every type, but only `never` can be assigned to `never`. So, while writing a small test in VS Code, I've ended up with the following:

```
function generateError(){
    throw new Error("oops");
}
function do(option: "opt1" | "opt2"){
    if(option === "opt1") return true;
    if(option === "opt2 ) return false;
    generateError();
}
let res = do("blah");
```

Well, what's the expected type of `res`? According to the compiler, it's `string | undefined` (which makes sense, though I must say I expected `string`). I guess I'm not seeing the point of having a new type just to represent functions that never return. Do we really need this concept? IS this just a compiler thing that helps it have better flow analysis?

Comment: The inferred return type should rather be `boolean`

Comment: I've covered it here as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/never.html

Comment: @basarat that link doesn't go anywhere anymore.

Comment: Updated : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/never

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never is information that this particular part shouldn't be reachable. For example in this code

```
function do(): never {
    while (true) {}
}
```

you have an infinite loop and we don't want to iterate infinite loop. Simply as that.

But a real question is how can it be useful for us?
It might be helpful for instance while creating more advanced types to point **what they are not**

for example, let's declare our own NonNullable type:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

Here we are checking if T is null or undefined. If it is then we are pointing that it should never happen. Then while using this type:

```
let value: NonNullable<string>;
value = "Test";
value = null; // error
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `never` to ensure that you won't miss a function contract.

```
function forever(): never {
    while (true) {
        break; // Error because you can't leave the function.
    }
}

enum Values {
    A,
    B
}

function choose(value: Values) {
    switch (value) {
        case Values.A: return "A";
    }

    let x: never = value; // Error because B is not a case in switch.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions that never (ever) return and functions that may throw are not quite the same thing.

For example:

```
function foo(option: "opt1" | "opt2"): string | undefined {
  if (option === "opt1") return true;
  if (option === "opt2") return false;
  throw new Error("unknown option");
}

function bar(option: "opt1" | "opt2"): never {
  while (true) {
    doOption(option);
  }
}
```

The first one may (or may not) return, but it can, so the return type cannot be `never`. If it can return a value, the return type obviously is not `never`.

The second one will never return. Not a value, not undefined, nothing. There is no case in which it will return, so the type can be `never`.

There are some functions that look like #2 but actually fall within #1, typically when `throw` is involved or if you're using `process.exit` in node (which can't return as it kills the process).

Comment: Hi ssube. So, if there's a chance of returning, it can't be of type never. Makes sense. But what's the point of never then? I'm having a hard time understanding why it was introduced in TypeScript...

Comment: The purpose is to explicitly note methods that won't return, like the `process.exit` example. Now that the compiler knows for sure, putting code after them can produce a warning, just like putting code after `return`.

Comment: Ah, so it's a compiler thing? Still, not sure on why it's there because I'm almost positive that the examples shown to justify its existence can be correctly inferred by the compiler without that type...again, I might be wrong...

Comment: How else would you describe the return type of `process.exit`?

Comment: ok, maybe in that case...still, not sure on where I'd use it in my programs. Probably in a couple of months I'll change my mind...